# Retrieving Data From Firestore in time

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have looked all over the internet for how to fix this problem and I can't find a solution anywhere. I am using flutter with firestore to make an app. I want to make it so when the user logins into the app at the top shows their name (simple right). I can get data from firestore:

```
Future<void> getName() async {
  print("Attemping to get name!");
  final firestoreInstance = await FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String uid = auth.currentUser.uid.toString();
  await firestoreInstance.collection("Users").doc(uid).get().then((value) {
    print("Name: " + value.data()["firstName"]);
    info.firstName=((value.data()["firstName"]));
  })

class info {
  static String firstName;
}
```

but it comes in too late so the app just says "Welcome back" [As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUtSR.png) and not "Welcome back, Connor" [As seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaXAC.png)

When I look in the console the function does run but the program doesn't wait for it and continues resulting in a null.

Thanks you

EDIT as requested UI code:

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  final DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance;
  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  static String firstName;
  static String lastName;
  static String email;
  static String companyName;
  static bool isNewAccount = false;
  static String name = "Welcome back";

  Home();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final User user = auth.currentUser;
    final uid = user.uid;
    final ref = DatabaseReference.reference();

    if (isNewAccount == true) {
      userSetup(firstName, lastName, email, companyName);
      isNewAccount = false;
    }

    getName(); //does get the name from the database but name will error out as it doesn't get the name fast enough (or that's what I think)
    name= "Welcome back, "+info.firstName;

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async => false,
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
          body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
              margin:
                  EdgeInsets.only(top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 16),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                    child: Text(
                      name,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 16,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 260,
                    height: 125,
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "CHECK-IN",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 40.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.grey[850],
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Checkin()));
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 260,
                    height: 140,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "CHECK-OUT",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 38.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.grey[850],
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => Checkout()));
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 55),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                          child: Text(
                            "Sign out: ",
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            child: Text(
                              "SIGN OUT",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.grey[700],
                            onPressed: () {
                              context.read<AuthenticationService>().signOut();
                              //return MyApp();
                            },
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                          child: Text(
                            "View Stats: ",
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            child: Text(
                              "STATS",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.grey[700],
                            onPressed: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Stats()));
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                          child: Text(
                            "View Profile: ",
                            style: new TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 15.0,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          child: RaisedButton(
                            child: Text(
                              "PROFILE",
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 14.0,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                            color: Colors.grey[700],
                            onPressed: () {
                              /*Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => Stats()));*/
                            },
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    width: 240,
                    height: 55,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 12),
                    child: RaisedButton(
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                      ),
                      child: Text(
                        "EMERGENCY REPORT",
                        style: new TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 20.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      color: Colors.grey[700],
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.push(context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => EmergencyReport()));
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  static getAccountDetails(
      String firstName1, String lastName1, String email1, String companyName1) {
    firstName = firstName1;
    lastName = lastName1;
    email = email1;
    companyName = companyName1;
    isNewAccount = true;
  }

  static getFirstName(String nameFirst) {
    name = "Welcome back, "+nameFirst;
  }
}
```

Comment: please add the code that builds the UI.

Comment: When the user login, you correctly get the data but since you didnt manage its state or changing the state value of ```Welcome back``` the ui didnt changed. try using setstate or provider. Check this example: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple

Comment: you cant get it in time but you can update the UI when it arrives, and await keyword before Firestore instance is not needed and uid is string so to String is not needed, use future builder

Comment: @Yadu I have tried using future builder before with no success. I also tried async and await. Could you by chance give an example?

Comment: it might be that you didnt use it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          future: firestoreInstance.collection("Users").doc(uid).get(),
          builder: (_,snap){
          return snap.hasData ? Text(snap.data.data()["firstName"]):CircularProgressIndicator();
        },)
```

Comment: This actually worked! Thank you very much! I do have another question. Now if I wanted to get data from the database and instead of putting that info on the screen (like we just did). Put it in a string to use later (like to get an email to use to send emails to that person later). When I tried to do that myself I would get the same problem where it wouldn't load quickly enough. Thank you

Comment: @ConnorOp please ask a new question and link this one. A starting point could be to create a variable outside of this FutureBuilder and as part of the builder function, assign that variable a value, e.g. snap.data.data()["firstName"])

Comment: @Scott Thank you. I posted the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64798049/retrieving-data-from-firestore-in-time-outside-of-widget-buildbuildcontext-con

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert StatelessWidget into StatefullWidget.
After that you have to write this in initState method

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
        getName().then((){
           setState(() {
               name= "Welcome back, "+info.firstName;
           });
        });  
}
```