# Retrieving Data From Firestore in time (outside of Widget build(BuildContext context) )

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

If you would like some context I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64778981/retrieving-data-from-firestore-in-time). In my flutter app you are able to send emails

```
  static getEmailCredentials(String email1, String password1) {
    email = email1;
    passw = password1;
  }

  sendMail() async {
    String username = email;//gets email from db 
    String password = passw;//gets password for email from db

    final SmtpServer = gmail(username, password); //fix one day

    final message = Message()
      ..from = Address(username)
      ..recipients.add("xxx@gmail.com")
      ..subject = "From "+name //need name here from db
      ..html = "<h3>" + emailContent.text + "</h3>";

    try {
      final SendReport = await send(message, SmtpServer);
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Message sent! Hang in there!",
        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
      );
    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      e.toString();
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: "Message failed to send! Try again?",
        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

As seen above. I know it's probably not the best to store the email and password but it works (well it would work if the data came in time). So my problem is I'll run this function at the beginning of the app but sometimes it won't load in on time.

UI Code:

```
class EmergencyReport extends StatelessWidget {
  EmergencyReport();

  static String email;
  static String passw;
  final TextEditingController emailContent = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    getEmailCredentialsF();//function that calls to db
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    DateTime weekAgo = now.subtract(new Duration(days: 7));
    DateFormat formadate = DateFormat('dd-MM');
    String formatedDate = formadate.format(now); // current date formatted
    String weekAgoForm =
        formadate.format(weekAgo); // date from week ago formatted
    countDocuments();
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  child: Container(
                    width: 54,
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 44),
                    child: FlatButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      },
                      child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios)],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Emergency Report",
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 10,
                  ),
                ),
                Card(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: TextField(
                        controller: emailContent,
                        maxLines: 8,
                        decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(
                            hintText: "Enter what happened here..."),
                      ),
                    )),
                Container(
                  width: 260,
                  height: 70,
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                    ),
                    child: Text(
                      "Send",
                      style: new TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 38.0,
                      ),
                    ),
                    color: Colors.grey[850],
                    onPressed: () {
                      if (emailContent.text != "") {
                        sendMail();
                        Navigator.of(context).pop();
                      } else {
                        Fluttertoast.showToast(
                          msg: "You need to put a message!",
                          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
                        );
                      }
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
void getEmailCredentialsF() {
  print("Attemping to get email!");
  final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String uid = auth.currentUser.uid.toString();
  firestoreInstance.collection("SendMailCredentials").doc("w1HsHFRgq7Oc3X9xUEnH").get().then((value) {
    EmergencyReport.getEmailCredentials((value.data()["email"]),(value.data()["password"]));
  });
}
```

Is there a way to make the code wait for that information to be gathered from the db before running the rest? I've tried await and async and future builders (could have used them wrong I am fairly new to flutter)

Thank you for all the help you give

Pic of UI if it helps [UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLO51.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yesterday I've answered you this

```
FutureBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
          future: firestoreInstance.collection("Users").doc(uid).get(),
          builder: (_,snap){
          return snap.hasData ? Text(snap.data.data()["firstName"]):CircularProgressIndicator();
        },)
```

now implement the same like
Lets say you have a Object which you keep saperate from UI

```
class MyDB{
 //...
}
```

and you need to get document in users collection

```
class MyDB{
  MyDB();
  Map<String,dynamic> userData;
  
  Future<void> getUser() async {
    userData = //...set
  }
}
```

and you want to get something else

```
class MyDB{
  MyDB();
  Map<String,dynamic> userData;
  Map<String,dynamic> someThingElse;

  Future<void> getUser() async {
    userData = //...set
  }
  Future<void> getSomeThingElse() async {
    someThingElse = //...set
  }
}
```

and you want to wait for all these data to be available before you show anything

```
class MyDB{
  MyDB();
  Map<String,dynamic> userData;
  Map<String,dynamic> someThingElse;

  Future<void> getUser() async {
    userData = //...set
  }
  Future<void> getSomeThingElse() async {
    someThingElse = //...set
  }
  
  Future getEveryThing() async {
    await getUser();
    await getSomeThingElse();
  }
}
```

now use that getEverything future in UI

```
final myDB = MyDB();
build(){
  return FutureBuilder<bool>(
    future: myDB.getEveryThing(),
    builder: (_,snap){
      if(snap.hasData){
        //myDB.userData and myDB.someThingElse will not be null
      }
      //if we are still waiting for the data
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    },);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your continuted help. I really appreciate it. When I tried to add your code I got this error "type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of 'Future<bool>' . Do yoi know what might cuase this. Here a paste bin of my code https://0bin.net/paste/p32HC1NY#Sl5S0vcBnprItthuYgnjy7X4qE4fXkRAm-bNVtDZGjF

Comment: https://0bin.net/paste/bdMgwIL9#o9L742iTdEJfZc9Nb7mO0YbpsRX1OwNOYJXZV2vlqZb errors

Comment: Update: So I got it to work with using this code
https://pastebin.com/R9dzcaTH
Is there something wrong with doing it this way?

Comment: you are handling map as String at getUser